# search for specific text not wrapped within an element

Tags: schematron

Hoping someone can help... been trying to figure out how to search for specific text that is not wrapped within an specific element.

The text "FIGURE" can appear anywhere within the XML document. The word FIGURE could also be spelled "Figure"...

This is what I have so far... but its not picking up on the literal text "FIGURE"...

```
  <rule context="text()">
      <assert test= "(.,'FIGURE')[not(/GRPHCREF)]" role="error" id="error_grphcref_figure"
      >Figure reference not wrapped in GRPHCREF.</assert>
  </rule>
```

Thanks so much for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to test whether a `text()` node contains the word "FIGURE", use the [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-contains) function. To compare case-insensitive, use the [`upper-case()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-upper-case) function, or you could test for `contains()` with the two literal strings "FIGURE" and "Figure".

The following rule asserts that if a `text()` node contains the word "FIGURE" (case-insensitive), then it must have a `GRPHREC` element ancestor.

```
<rule context="text()[contains(upper-case(.), 'FIGURE')]">
  <assert test= "ancestor::GRPHCREF" role="error" id="error_grphcref_figure"
            >Figure reference not wrapped in GRPHCREF.</sch:assert>
</rule>
```

Though I think it would be cleaner to separate value test for the context evaluation and the assertion test, as I have done above. However, below demonstrates how to keep your more general match on all `text()` nodes and apply all of the conditions within the assert test:

```
<rule context="text()">
  <assert test= "contains(upper-case(.), 'FIGURE') and ancestor::GRPHCREF" role="error" id="error_grphcref_figure"
            >Figure reference not wrapped in GRPHCREF.</sch:assert>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Exactly what is needed and I now understand why mine wasn't working.  I could extract was I was looking for utilizing XPath but could not get it to work in Schematron... thanks again for your time and effort! :)

Comment: Thanks again... hope its okay if I ask one more question... if I wanted perform a text() node search but ignore one element... how would I incorporate that into my rule? I've tried numerous iterations but its still picking up the one element I want it to ignore... any suggestions?

Comment: You want it to be valid if the text() node is a descendant if the GRPHCREF element or some other element? Change the assert test to: ancestor::GRPHCREF or ancestor::specialElement

Comment: Sorry... realizing I'm generalizing, hard to describe exactly what is needed - I'm leaving out important details - total newbie.  If the word FIGURE is contained within a GRAPHIC element then this is okay - do not want Schematron to flag this.  But if its anywhere else within the document then flag it.  So the rule is valid UNLESS the text() node is within a GRAPHIC element.  Does this make sense and is this possible? I've tried not(GRAPHIC) in the assert test and rule context... but to no avail. The overall rule is working fantastic, just wondering if it can be tweaked a little.

Comment: A relative XPath will be evaluated from the context node. In this case, that is the text() node, so not(GRAPHIC) is testing that the Text() node does not have a child element GRAPHIC, which will always be true, because a text node will never have any children.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and patience on this... I've been working on this off and on for two days now... so nice to have a resolution and learn what you're doing wrong and what your'e doing right... just awesome... :)